# Springboot Java webapp error : process finished with exit code 0

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

My app always exit. "process finished with exit code 0".
I tried with different versions of JAVA, Springboot but I get same issue everytime.

Below is the run output and POM file data

```
package com.technik.demotechnik;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemotechnikApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemotechnikApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.technik</groupId>
    <artifactId>demotechnik</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demotechnik</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Build log

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=64000:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-launcher/1.8.2/junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/Documents/work/nikunj/projects/java/demotechnik/target/test-classes:/Users/nikunjrai/Documents/work/nikunj/projects/java/demotechnik/target/classes:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/2.7.13/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.7.13/spring-boot-starter-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.7.13/spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.7.13/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.7.13/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.12/logback-classic-1.2.12.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.12/logback-core-1.2.12.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.17.2/log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.17.2/log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.36/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.30/snakeyaml-1.30.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync/4.6.1/mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.1.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/bson/4.6.1/bson-4.6.1.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.6.1/mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/bson-record-codec/4.6.1/bson-record-codec-4.6.1.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/3.4.13/spring-data-mongodb-3.4.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.3.28/spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.3.28/spring-context-5.3.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.28/spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.3.28/spring-expression-5.3.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.7.13/spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.7.13/spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.7.13/spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.13.5/jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.13.5/jackson-annotations-2.13.5.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.13.5/jackson-core-2.13.5.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.13.5/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.5.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.13.5/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.5.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.13.5/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.5.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.7.13/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.76/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.76/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.76.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.76/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.76.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.3.28/spring-web-5.3.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.28/spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.3.28/spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.28/lombok-1.18.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.7.13/spring-boot-starter-test-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-test/2.7.13/spring-boot-test-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/2.7.13/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.7.0/json-path-2.7.0.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.4.11/json-smart-2.4.11.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/net/minidev/accessors-smart/2.4.11/accessors-smart-2.4.11.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.3/asm-9.3.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/assertj-core-3.22.0.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest/2.2/hamcrest-2.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-5.8.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-api-5.8.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.8.2/junit-platform-commons-1.8.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.2/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-params-5.8.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.8.2/junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/4.5.1/mockito-core-4.5.1.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.12.23/byte-buddy-1.12.23.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.12.23/byte-buddy-agent-1.12.23.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/3.2/objenesis-3.2.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/4.5.1/mockito-junit-jupiter-4.5.1.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/1.5.1/jsonassert-1.5.1.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/external/google/android-json/0.0.20131108.vaadin1/android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.28/spring-core-5.3.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.28/spring-jcl-5.3.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/5.3.28/spring-test-5.3.28.jar:/Users/nikunjrai/.m2/repository/org/xmlunit/xmlunit-core/2.9.1/xmlunit-core-2.9.1.jar com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 @w@/private/var/folders/mx/tyh72g3d09z3m68qkqpns8sr0000gn/T/idea_working_dirs_junit.tmp @/private/var/folders/mx/tyh72g3d09z3m68qkqpns8sr0000gn/T/idea_junit.tmp -socket63999
14:41:45.585 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
14:41:45.596 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
14:41:45.629 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
14:41:45.641 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplicationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
14:41:45.645 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/technik/demotechnik/DemotechnikApplicationTests-context.xml] does not exist
14:41:45.645 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/technik/demotechnik/DemotechnikApplicationTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
14:41:45.646 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
14:41:45.646 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplicationTests]: DemotechnikApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
14:41:45.684 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplicationTests]
14:41:45.733 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/nikunjrai/Documents/work/nikunj/projects/java/demotechnik/target/classes/com/technik/demotechnik/DemotechnikApplication.class]
14:41:45.733 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplication for test class com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplicationTests
14:41:45.803 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplicationTests]: using defaults.
14:41:45.803 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
14:41:45.819 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@1863d2fe, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@1787bc24, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@544d57e, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@55c53a33, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@53b7f657, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@797b0699, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@5a37d3ed, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@26df6e3a, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@4a3631f8, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@6b58b9e9, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@f14a7d4, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@52e7a6b2, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@29a5f4e7, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@79c97cb, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@2d9caaeb]
14:41:45.822 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@34f6515b testClass = DemotechnikApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4b34fff9 testClass = DemotechnikApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.technik.demotechnik.DemotechnikApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5aebe890, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@1190200a, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@37271612, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@6f45df59, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@5609159b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@31610302], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.13)

2023-06-27 14:41:46.253  INFO 25047 --- [           main] c.t.d.DemotechnikApplicationTests        : Starting DemotechnikApplicationTests using Java 19.0.2 on Nikunjs-MacBook-Pro-2.local with PID 25047 (started by nikunjrai in /Users/nikunjrai/Documents/work/nikunj/projects/java/demotechnik)
2023-06-27 14:41:46.255  INFO 25047 --- [           main] c.t.d.DemotechnikApplicationTests        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-27 14:41:46.682  INFO 25047 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-27 14:41:46.690  INFO 25047 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2023-06-27 14:41:47.623  INFO 25047 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "4.6.1"}, "os": {"type": "Darwin", "name": "Mac OS X", "architecture": "x86_64", "version": "12.6"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/19.0.2+7-44"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@21c747a]}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
2023-06-27 14:41:47.635  INFO 25047 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:81}] to localhost:27017
2023-06-27 14:41:47.635  INFO 25047 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:80}] to localhost:27017
2023-06-27 14:41:47.635  INFO 25047 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=17, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=19258901}
2023-06-27 14:41:47.860  INFO 25047 --- [           main] c.t.d.DemotechnikApplicationTests        : Started DemotechnikApplicationTests in 2.003 seconds (JVM running for 2.861)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It's completely empty app.The main app was not working so I have created a new dummy app to test.this is dummy app my main app is also not working
I am trying to build Rest API app.I am new to JAVA.

Comment: What's the source code of `DemotechnikApplicationTests`?

Comment: It's completely empty app.The main app was not working so I have created a new dummy app to test.this is dummy app my main app is also not working.But I think the issue is not related to code.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the source code of `DemotechnikApplicationTests`. What's an "empty app"?

Comment: Did you forget @SpringBootApplication annotation?

Comment: @Egor no it's there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a silly mistake there. As I told I am new to JAVA, this was indeed my first code.
***I was running the package instead of app.***
It just runs the test and that's the output pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I do not have authority to comment directly so I add a answer here.

I tried your code on my local and it can start successfully without `Process finished with exit code 0`.

I checked your log and I think one possible problem is that your application has NOT been regarded as a web application.

The log ends with

```
2023-06-27 14:41:47.860  INFO 25047 --- [           main] c.t.d.DemotechnikApplicationTests        : Started DemotechnikApplicationTests in 2.003 seconds (JVM running for 2.861)
```

So please check whether you are running DemotechnikApplicationTests actually.

BTW, my local log includes the tomcat, please check whether it is correctly configured.

```
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.76]
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```